# Fill an Excel column with consecutive numbers of another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel, how can I fill column with 50 consecutive numbers, if exists, of another column,

There is a function or formula that I can use ?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want to get?

Comment: For exemple: Column A : 1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11 and column B, that want to fill it using function or Formula : 6,7,8,9,10. I simplify the exemple using just 5 consecutive numbers and not 50.

Comment: Just type `=A4` in B1 and fill down with that formula, then copy and paste as values

Comment: Either the [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) or [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) will do this. You just need to determine the minimum which is unclear unless it is 6 because that is the only way to get 5 consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for minimum number in a consecutive series of predetermined size then the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) with [OFFSET² function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) can compare a cell's value with a cell offset 49 rows further down the worksheet to see if they are numerically 49 apart. If the numbers are sorted and there are no duplicates then this will produce the minimum number where there are 49 consecutive numbers immediately following it. If the numbers are not sorted or there is a chance of duplicates then this condition cannot be guaranteed to be true and all 50 numbers would need to be checked.

In my sample (see below) for 5 consecutive in I2 as,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, K$2:K$22/(OFFSET(K$2:K$22, 4, 0)=K$2:K$22+4), 1)
```

The subsequent numbers were produced with a simple `=I2+1` filled down.

[image: lowest_numbers_in]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If column **A** contains unsorted data, then in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2-A1=1,1+B1,0)
```

and copy down.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(49,B:B,0)-50+ROWS($1:1))
```

and copy down:

[image]